# How do I select a record in a table using a combo box derived from a query?

Tags: ms-access

I have the following:

A **linked** table; `table_1` which contains the field `ID_A`

A **linked** table; `table_2` which contains the field `ID_B`

I need to join the two tables together however `ID_A` and `ID_B` contain unrelated values. As the two tables are linked from another database then my plan is to use a third table (`table_3`) that links two tables together by providing a cross reference for the two ID fields, i.e. there are `ID_A` and `ID_B` columns in `table_3` with each record being a cross reference pair. I figured I'd build a simple form for user to choose the pairs from dropdowns.

I've started off by building an append query that adds all the non-duplicate `ID_A` records to `table_3` and I figured I'd work out how to run this automatically every time a user opens the form. The user would then open the form which is linked to `table_3` and select an `ID_A` from the form using a dropdown. They would then assign an `ID_B` referenced from `table_2`.

Here's my issue though - in order for the user to match an `ID_B` to an `ID_A` they will need a bit more information about `ID_A` from another couple of fields in `table_1`. The standard Access wizard allows you to `Find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my combo box` however I am restricted to choosing a single field from `table_3`. I want to be able to display a combo box of a query that includes `ID_A` from `table_3` and `field_X` and `field_Y` from `table_1`.

I've tried creating a combo box from `Find a record on my form based on the value I selected in my combo box` and then looking at the `[Embedded Macro]` but it displays `="[ID_A] = " & Str(Nz([Screen].[ActiveControl],0))` which doesn't give me too many clues on how I might change this to give me the equivalent of the pseudo code; `ID_A = form_1.combobox_1.ID_A`.

Any ideas using the macro editor would be great but I have a very basic understanding of VBA so could try and employ a solution using that.

Comment: Modify the combobox properties, including RowSource, to whatever you want. I seldom use wizards.

Comment: I've built the combo box from the query fine. I just don't know how to create a macro to select the correct ```ID_A``` record from that combo box

Comment: Edit question to show sample data as text tables as well as desired output. Or go to another forum where providing file is accepted and encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Adding this VBA code to `After Update` in the `Event` menu works:

```
Private Sub combobox1_AfterUpdate()
    ' Find the record that matches the control.
    Dim rs As Object

Set rs = Me.Recordset.Clone
    rs.FindFirst "[ID_A] = " & Str(Nz(Me![combobox1], 0))
    If Not rs.EOF Then Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
End Sub
```